# find $\lim _ {y\rightarrow + \infty } \int _ { 1 } ^ { 2 } \frac { \ln ( x + y ) } { \ln \left(x^{2}+y^{2} \right) } d x$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, parametric

I need to find 
$$\lim _ {y\rightarrow + \infty } \int _ { 1 } ^ { 2 } \frac { \ln ( x + y ) } { \ln \left(x^{2}+y^{2} \right) } d x$$
Any hints?
PS. i tried to convert problem to solving improper integral. But nothing good happened

Answer (score 3):

By dominated convergence, you may move the limit operand inside, giving $\int_1^2\frac{dx}{2}=\frac12$.

Comment: wow, i did not see that. thanks

Answer (score 1):

As $y\to\infty$ the addition of $x/x^2$ does not greatly affect the values of the arguments of the functions, so the integral tends to
$$\int_1^2\frac{\ln{(y)}}{\ln{(y^2)}}\mathrm{d}x=\int_1^2\frac{\ln{(y)}}{2\ln{(y)}}\mathrm{d}x=\int_1^2\frac12\mathrm{d}x=\frac12(2-1)=\frac12$$